# python regex optional named groups

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm looking for a clean way to extract some data from a string using regex and the python `re` module. Each line of the string is of the form `key = value`. There are only certain keys that I'm interested in, but for some strings these keys may be missing. I can think of a few ways to do this by iterating over the string line by line, or by using `re.finditer()`, but what I'd really like to do is  use named groups and a single call to `re.match()`,  to end with a dictionary of groups using `.groupdict()` method of the returned match object. I can do that using named groups when all the groups are present, but it seems that if I make groups optional then they don't get matched even when present.

I'm probably missing something obvious, but is there a way to do this in a single regex or do I need a multistep process?

```py
import re

# trying to extract 'type', 'count' and 'destinations'.
# string1 has all keys and a single re.match works
# string2 is missing 'count'... any suggestions?

string1 = """
Name: default
type = Route
status = 0
count = 5
enabled = False
start_time = 18:00:00
end_time = 00:00:00
destinations = default
started = False
"""

string2 = """
Name: default
type = Route
status = 0
enabled = False
start_time = 18:00:00
end_time = 00:00:00
destinations = default
started = False
"""


pattern = re.compile(r"(?s).*type = (?P<type>\S*).*count = (?P<count>\S*).*destinations = (?P<destinations>\S*)")

m1 = re.match(pattern,string1)
# m1.groupdict() == {'type': 'Route', 'count': '5', 'destinations': 'default'}

m2 = re.match(pattern,string2)
# m2 == None
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Seems like it would be easier to split the lines with something like [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and parse the resultant list into a dictionary.

Comment: There's definitely a lot of ways it could be done, with iteration and `splitlines`, or something like `re.finditer(r'(?P<key>.*) = (?P<value>.*)',string)`,  I was really just interested in if theres a concise way to do it with a single regex to avoid extra work parsing it all to a dictionary.

Comment: Putting together and maintaining an extremely long and/or delicate regex seems like more work than at most 9 lines of parsing the same string into a dictionary.

Comment: It might end up being more complicated for sure, but I was thinking of a function to build up the required regex from a list of desired keys to keep it maintainable. Having spent a few hours trying to figure out the right regex, I kind of want to know for the sake of knowing if its possible at this point.

Comment: So, can all of these keys be missing, i.e. are they all optional? If yes, then it makes sense to use the solution like below. Or, you may use something like `dict(re.findall(r'(key1|key2|keyN)\s*=\s*(.+)',s))`

Comment: Well, a better regex would be `dict(re.findall(r'(?m)^(key1|key2|keyN)\s*=\s*(.+)',s))`. Why use `re.match` here? If you are after this kind of solution, I will post the code with dynamic regex building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check on this out.

```
#python 3.5.2
import re

# trying to extract 'type', 'count' and 'destinations'.
# string1 has all keys and a single re.match works
# string2 is missing 'count'... any suggestions?

string1 = """
Name: default
type = Route
status = 0
count = 5
enabled = False
start_time = 18:00:00
end_time = 00:00:00
destinations = default
started = False
"""

string2 = """
Name: default
type = Route
status = 0
enabled = False
start_time = 18:00:00
end_time = 00:00:00
destinations = default
started = False
"""

pattern = re.compile(r"""
(?mx)\A
(?=(?:[\s\S]*?^\s*type\s*=\s*(?P<type>.*)$)?)
(?=(?:[\s\S]*?^\s*count\s*=\s*(?P<count>.*)$)?)
(?=(?:[\s\S]*?^\s*destinations\s*=\s*(?P<destinations>.*)$)?)
""")

m1 = re.match(pattern, string1)
print (m1.groupdict())

m2 = re.match(pattern, string2)
print (m2.groupdict())
```

To try it online, please click [here](http://rextester.com/GRM47776).

Comment: why does this work?, what does "(?mx)\A" do?, why do you need "?="

Comment: @jcr, an exhaustive explanation can be found here https://regex101.com/r/maviqZ/1.

Answer (score 4):

You could solve this with one line of simple regular expression.

```
>> dict(re.findall(r'^(type|count|destinations) = (\S*)$', string1, re.MULTILINE))
{'count': '5', 'type': 'Route', 'destinations': 'default'}

>> dict(re.findall(r'^(type|count|destinations) = (\S*)$', string2, re.MULTILINE))
{'type': 'Route', 'destinations': 'default'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to the following dictionary comprehension, which splits and filters the key-value pairs based on an input tuple of desired field names:

```
import re

def regexandgroup(instr: str, savekeys: tuple):
    exp = '^(\w+)[ \t:=]+([\w:]+)$'
    match = re.findall(exp, instr, re.MULTILINE)

    return {group[0]: group[1] for group in match if group[0] in savekeys}
```

Which gives us:

```
>> print(regexandgroup(string1, ('type', 'count', 'destinations')))
{'type': 'Route', 'count': '5', 'destinations': 'default'}

>> print(regexandgroup(string2, ('type', 'count', 'destinations')))
{'type': 'Route', 'destinations': 'default'}
```

Comment: Thats a really nice solution to the extracting the values, thanks! I guess if savekeys was a set it'd be a little more efficient as the size of the required keys grows.

Comment: @excaza: possibly worth noting that `[\s:=]+` will match a single newline character, so the pattern will match two consecutive lines with one word each. It might be better to use `[ \t:=]+`. (Also, `:` isn't in `\w`, but the time fields aren't in the list so I guess it doesn't matter.)

Comment: @rici Shouldn't matter much in this context but I've incorporated the former, thanks! For the latter, `:` is already in the second capture group.

Comment: @excaza: ah, so it is...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `pandas` to do things all at once?  The following uses the regex from @andrei-odegov

```
import pandas as pd


# create a Series object from your strings
s = pd.Series([string1, string2])

regex = r"""
    (?mx)\A
    (?=(?:[\s\S]*?^\s*type\s*=\s*(?P<type>.*)$)?)
    (?=(?:[\s\S]*?^\s*count\s*=\s*(?P<count>.*)$)?)
    (?=(?:[\s\S]*?^\s*destinations\s*=\s*(?P<destinations>.*)$)?)
"""

# return a DataFrame which contains your results
df = s.str.extract(regex, expand=True)

print(df)


    type count destinations
0  Route     5      default
1  Route   NaN      default
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify if any field can be missing or if count is the only field that could be missing. However, this pattern will match all 3 cases that you suggested and it will store them in named capture groups.

`type = (?<type>\S*)|count = (?<count>\d+)|destinations = (?<destinations>\S*)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B7PDCx/4)

`|` just means or, so you're looking for `type = ...` OR `count = ...` OR `destinations = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the key/value pairs, then you can either ignore the additional keys, or else add `… if x.split(' = ')[0] in wanted_keys` to filter them. Use `setdefault` if you want to fill in missing keys.

```
>>> dict(x.split(' = ') for x in string1.strip().splitlines()[1:])
{'status': '0', 'count': '5', 'started': 'False', 'start_time': '18:00:00', 'enabled': 'False', 'end_time': '00:00:00', 'type': 'Route', 'destinations': 'default'}
```